# Usar PHPMailer e Ajax com Slim Framework

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer, slim

Sou iniciante no PHP e estou precisando tratar uma rota post usando Ajax, Slim e o PHPMailer.

No meu index onde tem o form estou usando esse código jquery para requisição Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/send-email',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('.form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.show').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Eu preciso saber, quais tratativas preciso fazer para que eu receba os dados do form e coloque em outro arquivo chamado send-form.php onde o PHPMailer irá trabalhar com esses dados.

```php
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\Views\PhpRenderer;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['renderer'] = new PhpRenderer("./src/views");

$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "index.html");
});

$app->get('/sobre', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "about.html");
});

$app->get('/contato', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "contact.html");
});

$app->get('/servicos', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "services.html");
});

$app->post('/send-email', function(Request $request, Response $response) {

});


$app->run();

?>
```

Esse aí é meu index.php com as rotas. O que devo fazer na rota post para que os dados cheguem no send-form.php?